# Is it ok to assign this to a static pointer in constructor as in example here

Tags: c++, static, constructor

I am using the approach below for convenience.  ie a convenient means of accessing the same myapp instance in a larger program.  The code compiles and runs correctly on my machine but want to ask if anyone sees any problems with this approach?

For example, the this ptr is assigned to the_app in the constructor?  Is that ok?  My concern is that object is still being constructed.  but if last line of constructor then ok?  Or is it because it is a pointer so doesn't matter because as long as used when fully constructed will be ptr to full object?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class myapp
{
public:
   myapp() : m_data(0)
   {
     the_app = this;
   }

   void DoIt() { cout << "doing it\n"; }

   static myapp* the_app;

private:
   int m_data;
};

myapp* myapp::the_app = 0;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
myapp app;

    app.DoIt();  //doing it using member function

    myapp::the_app->DoIt();  //accessing using static ptr
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What will happen when you instantiate another myapp?

Comment: Language note: I usually read "a = b" as "b is assigned to a" rather than "a is assigned to b".

Answer (score 1):

This is working as expected.
BUT there are a couple of issues:

- When the instance is deleted, the destructor should set the class variable back to zero. You didn't write about that.
- When another instance is created, the class variable changes and maybe this leads to the first instance getting lost...
- It does not seem like a good idea (just my personal impression)

Answer (score 1):

If what you are after is static access to a single instance of a class, then
you might want to check out the
[C++ Singleton design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern)

Comment: Yes I think this is probably best way to go

Answer (score 0):

It's not ok:

```
{
   myapp app;
}
myapp::the_app->DoIt();
```

This would be illegal, as `myapp::the_app` is a dangling pointer at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to initialize it, then no, you must explicitly define your static member variables and [initialize them there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1b5y48f.aspx):

> If the data member is to be explicitly initialized, an initializer
>   must be provided with the definition

There's only one per class, and is shared between all the objects. Static data members are accessed through static function members.

If you didn't mean to initialize, then you need to take into the account that each new instance of your class overwrites the value, and you always have the last pointer created. When your class is destructed - that pointer may become invalid.

Comment: He does do that - `myapp* myapp::the_app = 0;`

Comment: "No, you must explicitly define your static member variables and initialize them" He is doing that.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore better now? I was sure that people would read past the first sentence, but this assumption consistently doesn't hold with you:-/

Comment: When I read the answer, it only had the first part. Don't take it personally.

Answer (score 0):

Problems I can see:

1. If you subclass myapp, the subclass won't be fully constructed when the pointer is assigned.
2. The static pointer isn't cleared in the `myapp` destructor because you haven't written one. The pointer might live on after the object has been destroyed, if your real code doesn't have it on the stack of `main()`.
3. Multi-threading: If you are using multi-threading then you have a problem, since the assignment may be re-ordered before the rest of the `myapp` initialisation. Also assigning the pointer might not be atomic depending on the platform.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, problems are:

- a new instance could be created at some point, unexpectedly replacing your my_app instance
- a dangling pointer remains when the instance is destroyed
- when you derive from my_app, the pointer is assigned before the object is fully constructed.

You could alleviate the first two of these problems by adding

```
assert(the_app == NULL);
```

to your constructor and

```
the_app = NULL;
```

to your destructor.

Alternative solutions that come to mind:

```
std::scoped_ptr<my_app> the_global_app;
```

... if you use a single global object, you might as well admit that you are using a global variable. In your `main` function:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    the_global_app.reset( new myapp() ); // or a derived class

    the_global_app->DoIt();  //accessing using static ptr
    return 0;
}
```

If you don't intend to derive from `myapp`, you might even be tempted to use a plain global variable:

```
myapp the_global_app;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    the_global_app.DoIt();  //accessing using static ptr
    return 0;
}
```

... but then you need to be aware that other global objects defined in different source files might not have been initialized (`std::cout` is guaranteed to be available, though).